# Using RxJava and Okhttp

Tags: java, android, rx-java, okhttp

I want to request to a url using okhttp in another thread (like IO thread) and get `Response` in the Android main thread, But I don't know how to create an `Observable`.

Answer (score 20):

It's easier and safer to use `Observable.defer()` instead of `Observable.create()`:

```
final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<Response>>() {
    @Override public Observable<Response> call() {
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(new Request.Builder().url("your url").build()).execute();
            return Observable.just(response);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return Observable.error(e);
        }
    }
});
```

That way unsubscription and backpressure are handled for you. Here's [a great post by Dan Lew](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/07/23/deferring-observable-code-until-subscription-in-rxjava/) about `create()` and `defer()`.

If you wished to go the `Observable.create()` route then it should look more like in [this library](https://github.com/shekhargulati/rx-okhttp/blob/master/src/main/java/com/shekhargulati/reactivex/rxokhttp/DefaultOkHttpBasedRxHttpClient.java#L92) with `isUnsubscribed()` calls sprinkled everywhere. And I believe this still doesn't handle backpressure.

Answer (score 13):

I realise this post is a bit old, but there's a new and more convenient way of doing this now

```
Observable.fromCallable {
        client.newCall(Request.Builder().url("your url").build()).execute()
    }
```

More info: https://artemzin.com/blog/rxjava-defer-execution-of-function-via-fromcallable/

Comment: Could you please clarify the code? A `new` is missing before `Request`, and after that it throws an error

Comment: This is not Java, it's Kotlin

Comment: Ops... missed that, sorry

Comment: What versions of rxjava / okhttp are you using for this? newCall.execute() returns a Response object which isn't callable?

Comment: rxjava:2.1.5 / okhttp:3.9.0 - Callable means any method or function. Check this out: https://artemzin.com/blog/rxjava-defer-execution-of-function-via-fromcallable/

Comment: Ah yes it was the Kotlin that tripped me up, forgot to toss in the () -> {} for the Java call

Comment: Beware what happens when your subscription gets cancelled before... you would get one very generic error - UndeliverableException.

Answer (score 0):

I came late to the discussion but, if for some reason the code need to stream the response body, then `defer` or `fromCallable` won't do it. Instead one can employ the `using` operator.

```
Single.using(() -> okHttpClient.newCall(okRequest).execute(), // 1
             response -> { // 2
                 ...

                 return Single.just((Consumer<OutputStream>) fileOutput -> {
                     try (InputStream upstreamResponseStream = response.body().byteStream();
                          OutputStream fileOutput = responseBodyOutput) {
                         ByteStreams.copy(upstreamResponseStream, output);
                     }
                 });
             },
             Response::close, // 3
             false) // 4
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) // 5
      .subscribe(copier -> copier.accept(...), // 6
                 throwable -> ...); // 7
```

1. The first lambda executes the response **after upon subscription**.
2. The second lambda creates the observable type, here with `Single.just(...)`
3. The third lambda disposes the response. With `defer` one could have used the try-with-resources style.
4. Set the `eager` toggle to `false` to make the disposer called after the terminal event, i.e. after the subscription consumer has been executed.
5. Of course make the thing happen on another threadpool
6. Here's the lambda that will consume the response body. Without `eager` set to `false`, the code will raise an IOException with reason 'closed' because the response will be already closed before entering this lambda.
7. The `onError` lambda should handle exceptions, especially the `IOException` that cannot be anymore caught with the `using` operator as it was possible with a try/catch with `defer`.

Answer (score 0):

Okhttp3 with RxSingle background API call.

```
     Disposable disposables = Single.fromCallable(() -> {
        Log.e(TAG, "clearData: Thread[" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "]");
        OkHttpClient client = Util.getHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + Util.getUserToken())
                .url(BuildConfig.BASE_URL + ApiConstants.DELETE_FEEDS)
                .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        if(response.isSuccessful()) {
           ...
           return ; // Any  type
        } else {
           return ; // Any type        
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .subscribe((result) -> {
           Log.d(TAG, "api() completed");
      });


    compositeDisposable.add(disposables);
```

Comment: keep in mind that if you close the subscription before the http call completes, it will crash.

Comment: @f.khantsis then what is the way to avoid this, wrap the HTTP call with try-catch

Comment: If you do that, you will lose out on exceptions.

I just created a `MaybeFromUnsafeCallable` call which mimicks the MaybeFromCallable, but does not throw exception when the function threw an exception after the subscription was already closed. Ditto ObservableFromUnsafeCallable etc..