# How to call multiple requests with okhttpclient and RxJava but without retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, okhttp

I have a list of URLs that I need to call and if I got success response for all of them, I can continue.

I can simply do it with RxJava and Retrofit like:

```
@PUT
fun uploadFile(@Url url: String, @Body file: RequestBody): Single<Response<Void>>


Observable.fromIterable(uploadUrls)
    .flatMapSingle {
        val requestBody = InputStreamRequestBody(contentResolver, uri)
        upsellServiceApi.uploadFile(url, requestBody)
    }
    .toList()
    .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
    .observeOn(schedulerProvider.ui())
    .subscribe(
        { responses ->
            if (responses.all { it.isSuccessful }) {
                // continue
            } else {
               //error
            }
        },
        {
            // error
        }
```

Now I need to do the same thing without retrofit and by only using okhttpclient. How should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it

```
Observable.fromIterable(uploadUrls)
    .map {
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).put(InputStreamRequestBody(contentResolver!!, uri)).build()
        okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute()
    }
    .collect(
        {
            mutableListOf<Response>()
        },
        {
                list: MutableList<Response>, response: Response -> list.add(response)
        }
    )
    .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
    .observeOn(schedulerProvider.ui())
    .subscribe(
        { responses ->
            if (responses.all { it.isSuccessful }) {
                // continue
            } else {
                // error
            }
        },
        {
            // error
        }
    ).also { compositeDisposable.add(it) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library like https://github.com/liujingxing/rxhttp to keep using RxJava.  Or implement it yourself [Using RxJava and Okhttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32687921/using-rxjava-and-okhttp)

If you don't want to use RxJava, then just enqueue and handle callback methods yourself.